# Make a pure JavaScript object from text to drag and drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have a Javascript drag and drop quiz for children

For example, they may have to make a sentence out of five images with “sat” “on” “the” “chair” “John”

The problem is all these images have to be specifically created.

Is there a way for pure Javascript to take the text “sat” and make it an object that could be used to drag and drop instead of images?

The current code (which only has images of letters to spell words) is:

```
function addDivs(mdiv,numA,preD,isOn){
    var tdiv = document.getElementById(mdiv);
    for(var i=0; i<numA.length;i++){
        var sLet = String(numA[i]);
        var turl = String("img/"+sLet+".gif");
        var sdiv = document.createElement("div");
        sdiv.style.width = "80px";
        sdiv.style.height = "80px";
        sdiv.id = String(preD+sLet);
        sdiv.style.margin = "5px";
        sdiv.style.display = "inline-block";
        if(isOn){
            sdiv.style.backgroundImage="url("+turl+")";
            sdiv.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
            sdiv.addEventListener('dragstart',drag);
            sdiv.draggable = true;
        }else{
            sdiv.style.background = "white";
            sdiv.addEventListener('drop',drop);
            sdiv.addEventListener('dragover',allowDrop);
        }

        tdiv.appendChild(sdiv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question lacks a lot about information. Can you please provide your current code solution, and mark where you want to go are what you want to achieve.

Comment: JonathanIn effect, all I want is that, instead of a div being created with a backround image of a letter, it creates a text box, or similar, which has the letter or letters put into the .value so that the object with the letters or letter can be draged into the correct position. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same question, the soution (given to me by a programmer) for replacing the image of letters is fairly simple

```
//Replace the following lines of code in the above question

sdiv.style.backgroundImage="url("+turl+")";
sdiv.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";

// with the following two lines

sdiv.className ='stpder';
sdiv.textContent = sLet;

//define the following in the CSS

.stpder{
    background-color: white !important;
    font-size: 68px;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px;
}
```